# Упаковка вэб приложения на Angular для Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, angular

Подскажите вэб приложения сделанные на Angular 4 можно упаковать через андроид студио для использования на телефоне или его все таки нужно переписывать на Java?

А так же приложение на андроиде и вэб приложение смогут использовать одну базу данных?

Comment: Зачем его упаковывать? В браузере открываете и пользуете.

Comment: Потому что нужно приложение на андроид а не вэб сайт

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я понимаю, речь идет о создании не нативных мобильных приложений. Да, это возможно.
Например, Ionic Framework позволяет это сделать - https://ionicframework.com.
Еще есть PhoneGap.